# RxJava chaining observables and error handling(custom exception propagation)

Tags: rx-java

I have 5 `Observable`s that're chained with `flatMap`. In case first four `Observable`s produce an `Exception` I want to propagate a different type of `Exception` to the fifth.

How is it achieved?

Thanks.

P.S.
I've come up with this yet untested solution:

```
flatMap(
        // onNext
        new Func1<BoolResponse, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(BoolResponse boolResponse) {
                return request;
            }
        },
        // onError
        new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                return Observable.error(new SomethingWentWrong());
            }
        },
        // onCompleted
        new Func0<Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call() {
                return request;
            }
});
```

Do you think it's OK?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you're looking for is `onErrorResumeNext` which will allow you to catch any `Throwable` emitted from the source and allows you to either resume with a new Observable or another `Observable` which would emit a different `Throwable`.

```
    ...
    .flatMap(...)
    .flatMap(...)
    .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
            // Here simply return an Observable which will emit the Throwable of your liking
            return Observable.error(new Throwable(...));
        }
    })
    .flatMap(...);
```

Keep in mind that `flatMap` is an operator to handle your stream of data but it will not allow you to handle `onError` has in your code example.  You can handle the error in your `Observer`'s `onError` callback where you subscribe to the stream.